# SharePoint 2013 group list task and subtask via the rest api not working

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, task-list

I am trying to fetch task and sub-task from a list via the rest api and display the in a page.

here is my html:

```
<div id="divSubTaskItems">

</div>
<p>Get Site List via REST API Call</p>
```

here is my call:

```
function getListData() {

    var fullUrl = "siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items?$select=*,ParentID/Id&$expand=ParentID";

    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
    });
}

function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var mainTasks = [];
    var subTasks = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].ParentID.Id) {
            subTasks.push(data[i]);
        } else {
            mainTasks.push(data[i]);
       }
    }

    $("#divTaskItems").html(mainTasks);


    $("#divSubTaskItems").html(subTasks);
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    console.log('Error!');
}
```

The only thing that displays on my page is the

tag.

Thanks in advance.